# Nginx as SSL reverse proxy configuration = connection failure

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker-compose

I would like to use nginx as a SSL front end to an apache HTTP website. I've reduced my configuration to the simplest:

Nginx default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

#Work in progress
server {
    listen 443 ssl default;
    
    ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/certs/pem-1620200742-1020479.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/certs/mycomp.com.key;
    

    location / {    
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://wip:80;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '2'
services:
    reverse:
        image: nginx
        container_name: reverse
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443    #This addition solves the problem!!! 
        networks: 
            - mynet
        volumes:
            - ./reverse/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./reverse/ssl:/etc/ssl/certs      
    wip:
        image: httpd:2.4
        container_name: wip
        environment:
          TZ: "France/Paris"
        ports:
            - 8096:80
        networks: 
            - mynet                 
networks:
    mynet:
        driver: "bridge"
        ipam:
            driver: default
```

everything looks fine in logs:

nginx:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
172.18.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2021:09:15:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.43" "-"
```

Nginx starts fine, get 80 connnections but nothing about 443 connections

When browsing https://127.0.0.1 I get "connection failure". Same using the following command:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 443
```

It seams that nginx is not listening to 443

I've checked network issues using tinyweb. The 443 port is not blocked by a firewall or anything.

Do you have any clue what's wrong with my nginx configuration?

Comment: Your nginx is fine. On the `reverse` _container_ you only exposed post 80, not port 443, so it is not accessible from outside the container.

Comment: Yes! that is the solution thank you